# Scipy UnivariateSpline error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=3

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to increase the brightness of a gray-scale image. To do that I want to create a spline. But when I am trying to use scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline, it is raising an error.

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-289216dd01e1> in <module>
      8 x=[0,128,255]
      9 y=[0,190,255]
---> 10 myLUT=spline_to_lookup_table(x,y)

<ipython-input-38-289216dd01e1> in spline_to_lookup_table(spline_breaks, break_values)
      1 def spline_to_lookup_table(spline_breaks: list, break_values: list):
----> 2     spl = UnivariateSpline(spline_breaks, break_values)
      4     return spl(range(256))

~/anaconda3/envs/computer-vision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py in __init__(self, x, y, w, bbox, k, s, ext, check_finite)
    200 
    201         # _data == x,y,w,xb,xe,k,s,n,t,c,fp,fpint,nrdata,ier
--> 202         data = dfitpack.fpcurf0(x, y, k, w=w, xb=bbox[0],
    203                                 xe=bbox[1], s=s)
    204         if data[-1] == 1:

error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=3
```

Source code:

```
def spline_to_lookup_table(spline_breaks: list, break_values: list):
    spl = UnivariateSpline(spline_breaks, break_values)
    return spl(range(256))
x=[0,128,255]
y=[0,190,255]
myLUT=spline_to_lookup_table(x,y)
img_curved=cv2.LUT(img_gray, myLUT).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: yes. I didn't add openCV because I didn't think it was an issue with openCV. However, I am updating the tags.

Comment: the first call to an OpenCV function happens *after* the exception. please simplify your code and adjust tags to those that are relevant to the issue. adding unrelated tags appears as if you just want to increase visibility of your question.

Comment: By increasing, number of elements in x and y, it worked(x=[0, 64, 128, 192, 256],y=[0, 70, 140, 210, 256]). Maybe, it didn't get enough anchor points to implement the curve filter. Still looking for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot fit a cubic spline with three points: even a single cubic  parabola has four parameters.